# Artinian rings where all injective hulls of simple modules have finite length

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ be a unitary artinian ring. Suppose additionally that the injective hulls of all simple modules have finite length (or, equivalently, are finitely generated).

> Does the ring $A$ have to possess a Morita self-duality? Is there any such ring $A$ which is not an Artin algebra?

In order to try to answer to this I looked at "Finiteness of the injective hull", Rosenberg and Zelinski; "The dual notion of "finitely generated"", Vámos; "On co-noetherian rings", Jens. The paper "Co-Artinian rings and Morita duality", Miller and Turnidge, may be useful but I don't have access to it.

Comment: Did you look at http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdffirstpage_1&handle=euclid.tmj/1178242760?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thank you very much. At first sight I cannot find an immediate answer, but I will look at it carefully.